# Deep eager load in J2EE entities

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jta

I have a 3 layers model in my J2EE using EJB application: Cart, which has many LineItems, each having many Books (Book doesn't necessarily refers to a Line Item, it's not 2-directional).

```
Cart(1) <--> (M) LineItem (1) --> (M) Book
```

I wish to have it all eager loaded, i.e. when I extract the Cart it should also load all its Line Items and all of those Books with minimal number of SQL queries (I'm using a relational DB, e.g. MySQL). It can be done with 3 queries, one for each type of object. Setting "FetchType.EAGER" cause all objects to be loaded, however it has "2+n" calls: 1 query for the cart (obviously), another query for the Line Items, but then had to go on n queries for books, where n is the number of line items.

I used to work with Ruby on Rails, where using eager load (using includes) would do what I need. Can I do it also with J2EE?

(note: join might be an option, but I wish the entities to be populated automatically from the query, although I think the join is less comfortable).

Sample of my code:

```
@Entity
public class Cart implements Serializable {
    @OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="cart", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<LineItem> lineItems;
}

@Entity
public class LineItem implements Serializable {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="cart_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Cart cart;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Book book;
}

@Entity
public class Book implements Serializable {
   ...
}
```

Here is an example of the SQL queries where the Cart has 3 Line Items:

```
SELECT id, name FROM carts WHERE (id = 19)
SELECT id, quantity, book_id, cart_id FROM line_items WHERE (cart_id = 19)
SELECT id, description, name, price FROM books WHERE (id = 4)
SELECT id, description, name, price FROM books WHERE (id = 3)
SELECT id, description, name, price FROM books WHERE (id = 1)
```

Comment: We need to know which version of EE (or actually JPA) you are targeting, and if you want a pure EE/JPA solution - or are ok with using features propritary for a specific JPA implementation (if so, which one).

Answer (score 1):

Standard JPA provides [join fetch](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from#LEFT_OUTER_INNER_JOIN_FETCH_), which marks a relation to be fetched eagerly, as if it was marked eager via annotation. In your case, it is only necessary to `join fetch` `lineItems`, as `book` will be eagerly loaded with each `LineItem` in single query.

With JPA 2.1, you may use [Entity graph](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/) - you don't need to modify your query, you just attach a descriptor to your query that defines which relations should be eagerly fetched.

If you want to optimize to the smallest amount of queries possible, you might want to use [batch fetching](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/QueryOptimization), which is available in some JPa providers. But beware, there is no standardized way to turn this on - I just linked to how to do it with EclipseLink.

Comment: In hibernate the same could be achieved with `@Fetch(JOIN)` - this will always load the relationship using join so it is always eager. But generally `join fetch` is the way to go as @OndrejM pointed out.

Comment: Using the fist method of "join fetch" it results in multiple rows per top-level object (i.e. as the join found multiple results for the Cart, it duplicated the rows and didn't translate into a single Cart with multiple lines).

Comment: I don't understand, at which level do you get duplicated rows? If you want single query to retrieve an entity and all entities in its collection, the records in the SQL result must carry duplicate values if there are multiple related entities. SQL result is a table and not a tree, columns that attribute to the root entity have always the same data.

Comment: I know SQL result is a table, but if the ORM don't know to overcome that (and filter a single record for the top-level and multiple records as required for the relations), and if that is not a built-in feature of the ORM, not sure the "join fetch" is really usable at all. I believe other language ORM can do that.